# Copy or export Remmina remote desktop files to another Ubuntu install

Tags: rdp, remmina

Is there a way to do a bulk copy or export of all my Remmina connections? I have the option to export one by one, but with 50 connections this seems ridiculous. I tried looking for a connections file, or conf file, or something similar but cannot find anything.

`sudo find / -name 'remmina'` only returns four results:

```
/usr/share/menu/remmina
/usr/share/doc/remmina
/usr/bin/remmina
/usr/lib/remmina
```

...but none of them contain any connection files/entries :(

Comment: You mean like your past connections etc? What format would like the it to be in - is this so you can use remmina with the same data elsewhere?

Comment: Have you searched your home directory? `find /home/USER -iname "*remmina*"`

Comment: Well, I mean any connections that I've created and saved in the Remmina remote desktop client. The same way you can copy a folder in Windows that contains many .RDP files from one Windows cpu to another, I'm trying to find a way to do that on my Ubuntu 13.10 installations.

Comment: Thanks @chaos! I was a victim of hidden files/folders. I found all the .remmina files in my home folder. Happy camper :D

Comment: As a tip for the next time: your `find` command finds only files or dir named *exactly* remmina. Try `find / -iname "*remmina*"` or better (faster for these searches for files that do not change a lot) `locate -i remmina`. HTH. (oops --- missed @chaos comment before --- leave this for `locate`)

Comment: **also wanted to mention none of the passwords retained, but that's probably a good thing**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The files you need should be either in `~/.remmina` *(the hidden .remmina folder in your home directory)* or in `~/.local/share/remmina` (for newer versions).

For SSH, the known hosts are stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts.`.

All your user settings, preferences, etc for your user are stored in your home directory, as that is the only folder you by default have permissions to access.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case today. I have Remmina 1.2.0 installed and after creating a session, there is no Remmina folder, hidden or not, in my home folder. The Wiki confirms what you're saying but I found them in `~/.local/share/remmina`

Comment: I am just now coming back to Ubuntu for another check on it's integrity. I installed Skype a year or two ago (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and it broke my entire OS installation; had to reformat and lose a bunch of data so I've been using Windoh's again ever since with RDP (flawlessly, of course). Hopefully either Remmina or a similar product will work better in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS... cause I'm not a fan of Windoh's, I just use it because it lets me be productive.

Comment: Didn't know RDP could be got in windows to work flawlessly (probably just graphics drivers for me :) Anyway, the files are probably there now so it complies with the XDG spec. Also skype and other third party proprietary binary packages will work with Ubuntu etc - just if possible DO NOT use the `.run`, `.tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` etc packages provided and try and find a package for your distro (.deb file) that works.

Comment: @00fruX perhaps now Skype has hit 'beta' for linux it may work better https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/03/02/skype_for_linux_reaches_beta/ :/

Comment: @Wilf, maybe Skype will work. Either way. Just set up a new 16.04 server, *finally* figured out how to partition/format/mount a new 8 TB drive. Installed webmin, now SSH doesn't let remote connections and webmin itself stopped working. Not using ufw, ssh is running, and listening on 22. Webmin even says running on 10000, and again, no firewall here, but the server responds to nothing. BRB in another 2 years....

Answer (score 9):

For users of the [Flatpak build of Remmina](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.remmina.Remmina), you can find the connection settings at:

```
~/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/
```

Answer (score 8):

Installed Remmina on Ubuntu 16.04 and had to reinstall Ubuntu after a while because it wasn't running the best. On my first install, the location of all the Remmina connection files was `/home/$USER/.local/share/remmina/` folder (`$USER` is the current user).

After I reinstalled my new setup of Ubuntu put all the connection files in the same location `/home/$USER/.local/share/remmina/` and started up Remmina I had no connection. After reading this post, I created a new connection and seen a new folder created under `/home/$USER/.remmina/` with that connection, so I copied all my connections into that folder `/home/$USER/.remmina/`.

```
sudo cp -r /home/$USER/.local/share/remmina/* /home/$USER/.remmina/
```

I am just backing up @Wilf.

Answer (score 5):

For **Remmina 1.4.8** on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** the location of Remmina configuration was (for me):

```
~/snap/remmina/4460/.local/share/remmina
```

Today, I converted from a PPA install (which is [no longer supported after 1.4.8)](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/#ubuntu-and-linux-mint) to a snap install.  I copied all files from the old to new location.  Other than passwords, it worked well after:

```
sudo apt remove remmina # uninstalls program, leaves config information files
sudo snap install remmina --edge # install the snap remmina
sudo snap connect remmina:avahi-observe :avahi-observe # servers discovery
sudo snap connect remmina:cups-control :cups-control # printing
sudo snap connect remmina:mount-observe :mount-observe # mount management
sudo snap connect remmina:password-manager-service :password-manager-service # password manager

cp ~/.remmina/* ~/snap/remmina/4460/.local/share/remmina # copy profiles to new location for snap install
```

Comment: This was helpful for me. Thank you. For me though my old connections were saved in the `~.local/share/remmina` directory. I had to copy them all to the `~/snap/remmina/4460/.local/share/remmina` directory. Afterwhich I exited and started Remmina again, and they all showed up.

Comment: I used this: `cp .remmina/* ~/snap/remmina/current/.local/share/remmina/`

Answer (score 2):

#### Backup

```
tar -czf ~/remmina_backup.tgz ~/.local/share/remmina/ ~/.config/remmina/ ~/.local/share/keyrings ~/.ssh/
```

#### Restore

```
cd
tar -xf ~/remmina_backup.tgz
```

#### Snap users Backup

```
tar -czf ~/remmina_backup.tgz ~/snap/remmina/<version>/.local/share/remmina/ ~/snap/remmina/<version>/.config/remmina/ ~/.local/share/keyrings ~/.ssh/
```

Comment: Be careful you don't overwrite and lose existing data in `.ssh/` and `.local/share/keyrings/` during restore.  A merge may be required.

Answer (score 1):

Remmina connection files are usually stored in one of these folders:

- `~/.local/share/remmina`
- `~/.config/remmina`
- `~/.remmina/` (old versions)

The file names are `your_connection_name.remmina`. After you find right folder (e.g. `~/.local/share/remmina`) the backup & restore procedure is:

**Backup and transfer example (PC1)**

Example: connection files were found in `~/.local/share/remmina`

```
cd ~/.local/share/remmina
tar -cvzf all_my_connections.tgz *
scp all_my_connections.tgz my_user@my_new_linux_PC:/home/my_user/.
```

**Remmina installation and connection restore (PC2)**

User is logged-in as a my_user

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina

cd ~
ls -l .config/remmina
mv all_my_connections.tgz  ~/.config/remmina
cd .config/remmina
tar -xvzf all_my_connections.tgz
```

Important steps must be done after file restore:

- Open Remmina application window, press Ctrl+P (or right click to **Remmina main menu** button, i.e. three dashes below each other, and go to Remmina Preferences).
- Set Remmina data folder to `my_user/.config/remmina`
- Close preferences, close Remmina window.
- Open Remmina window again. The connections shoud be restored and visible.

Comment: Why not copy into the Remmina data folder given by default?
`~/.local/share/remmina`
Wouldn't that be safer?

Answer (score 0):

For **Remmina 1.2** on **Ubuntu 16.10 LTS** the location of Remmina configuration is:

> ~/snap/remmina/